# Concat a sublist of strings intro string elements of a list

Tags: python-3.x

Say I have a list of substrings `[["hello", "how", "are", "you?"], ["I'm", "doing", "great"]]` and I wanted to create a list of `["hello how are you?", "I'm doing great"]` how would one go about this?

I've tried

```
sum(mylist, [])
>> ["hello", "how", "are", "you?", "I'm", "doing", "great"]
```

and also

```
new_list = []
for i in mylist:
    new_list += i
>> ["hello", "how", "are", "you?", "I'm", "doing", "great"]
```

And neither seem to what I want it to do. I suspect that I need to join the subarrays first, and then append them maybe to a new list. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Once more the goal is to take:

```
[["hello", "how", "are", "you?"], ["I'm", "doing", "great"]]
```

and make it into:

```
["hello how are you?", "I'm doing great"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to do it is use list comprehension:

```
nested_lists = [["hello", "how", "are", "you?"], ["I'm", "doing", "great"]]
joined_list = [' '.join(str_list) for str_list in nested_lists]
print(joined_list)
# Outputs ['hello how are you?', "I'm doing great"]
```

essentially list comprehension merges a loop and list construction in the same construct - see line 2.

Answer (score 0):

```py
my_list = [["hello", "how", "are", "you?"], ["I'm", "doing", "great"]]
new_list = []
for mini_list in my_list:
  new_list.append(' '.join(mini_list)
```

This would therefore, take each item from that list which itself is a list and join them.
It will then append it to what I'm calling the new_list to give you the result you want.

Comment: `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`. Did you mean `for mini_list in my_list`?

Comment: Very cool, this works as well! Thank you! I got the gist of it.

Comment: That's right, i'll just correct that haha

Answer (score 0):

Just mapping all sublists with `' '.join`:

```
new_list = [*map(' '.join, mylist)]
```

Or one character shorter:

```
*new_list, = map(' '.join, mylist)
```

Comment: So many ways to do this, thank you for your input! :)